# What are all the syntactic elements of a Python function tooltip?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, documentation

Pointing at `sorted` in VS Code, the following popup appears:

[image: Python sorted function tooltip]

This contains lots of syntax elements I don't know from Python, such as `/`, `*`, `_T`, `@`; and coming from C++, it looks as if `SupportsRichComparison` is similar to a C++20 *Concept* but what is it really?

Also, how do I distinguish what the two different overloads are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bit of a train wreck. It boils down to this:

- If you only pass an iterable to `sorted` (so that the keyword argument `key` gets its default value `None`), then there has to be a way to compare the elements to determine an ordering.
- If you *do* provide a `key` argument, then you can have an arbitrary iterable, because the value of `key` will be used to "map" the values to things that *can* be compared.

Regular parameters can be specified via positional arguments or keyword arguments.

Parameters that precede `/` are positional-only: you cannot specify values for them using keywords arguments. (`sorted(__iterable=[1,2,3])` would be illegal.)

Parameters that follow `*` are keyword-only: you can *only* specify values for them using keyword arguments.  (`sorted([1,2,3], f)` would be illegal.)

`_T` is a type variable: it represents a specific but unknown type, basically used to tie the type hint for `__iterable` to the type hints for `key`.

`SupportsRichComparison` looks to be a `typing.Protocol`, which means it is basically an abstract base class that asserts its subclasses provide definitions for `__lt__` et al. Note that either the elements of `__iterable` are instance of `SupportsRichComparison`, or they are instances of some class `_T` that `key` knows how to convert to instances of `SupportsRichComparison`.

I am at a loss for how to explain `@`. It doesn't conform to any actual Python syntax that I am aware of; it *might* simply be some sort of conventional separator used to construct a type variable from some other pieces of information.

---

As a concrete example, consider complex numbers. Two complex numbers are not directly comparable:

```
>>> sorted([3+4j, 6-7j])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'complex'
```

But integers are comparable:

```
>>> sorted([4, -7])
[-7, 4]
```

So if you had some function that could map `3 + 4j` to `4` and `6-7j` to `-7`, you could sort the original list of complex numbers.

```
>>> sorted([3+4j, 6-7j], key=lambda x: x.imag)
[(6-7j), (3+4j)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Reading this extremely closely, I think (1) the `T` is actually not part of the typing.Protocol name because it's used in the second overload without `T`. The `T` here seems to indicate yet another type variable for a type that implements the protocol. (2) `key: None = ...` looks as if the type is `None` and that just implicitly has the default value `None`. (I wonder why they don't give default values; for example we know that it sorts with `reverse=False` by default...)

Comment: `T` is just an ordinary type variable (`typing.TypeVar`), not a protocol. The `@` as syntax would have to be the matrix multiplication operator, but I am unaware of the `typing` module making any use of it.

Comment: The `@` is really just the scope of the type variable, it seems. Using the info in this answer, it's easy enough to create my own function with `MyT = TypeVar("MyT") ; def MyF(x: MyT) -> MyT:  pass` and on mouseover it will show `MyT@MyF` in the tooltip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241182/discussion-between-felix-dombek-and-chepner).

Comment: I missed your first comment; cleaning this up now.